# Dependencies in the spring boot parent not picked without explicit mention of version

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, maven, dependencies, dependency-management

In main pom, I have parent declared as below.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.18</version>
        <relativePath />
</parent>
```

In the dependency section, have mentioned below

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<!--                <version>${hibernate.version}</version> -->
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

In child pom,

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<!--            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I tried to compile, getting below error,

```
 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar is missing.
```

From [this source](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-starter-parent):
*Once we’ve declared the starter parent in our project, we can pull any dependency from the parent by just declaring it in our dependencies tag. We also don’t need to define versions of the dependencies; Maven will download jar files based on the version defined for the starter parent in the parent tag.*

But its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the entry from dependencyManagement. Just declare the dependency.

Comment: Thanks. Its Ok now. Can you explain ?

Comment: The starter parent already has the dependencyManagement. If you have your own, you override it.